# Creating and returning a set in java then use toString in main to print to print the new set out

Tags: java

This is a question which needs to be answered using the methods shown here and no other way (its a exam question).

I have a `Person`and `Friends`(TreeSet to hold Person) class

The Person class just creates a instance of person with a sName and fName.

In friends I have a method `getSurname()` which finds the surname of the object Person and adds it to a new set with all matching surnames:

```
//Gets the surname of the object and create a new set
public TreeSet<Person> getSurname(String s){
    TreeSet<Person> surname = new TreeSet<Person>();

    for(Person currentPerson : friendsSet) { 
        if(currentPerson.getsName().equals(s)) {
            surname.add(currentPerson);
        }
    }

    return surname;

}

public String toString() {
    return "Friends [friendsSet=" + friendsSet + "]";
}
```

The problem occurs when in main I call the toString() method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Friends f = new Friends();  

        f.add(new Person("Rosella", "Murphy"));
        f.add(new Person("Mary", "O Keefe"));


        f.add(new Person("Rosella", "O Keefe"));
        //toString here
        System.out.printf("There should be 2 people with the surname 'O Keefe: %s",f.getSurname("O Keefe").toString());
}
```

It only prints out "Mary", "O Keefe" it should also print out "Rosella", "O Keefe".

[image]

I am returning a new TreeSet(getSurname()) with the surnames that match the parameter used in the method.

Then calling the method and then calling toString() method to print all the names in the new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the implementation of the Person class, I can't debug your exact issue, but likely your problem lies in your implementation of the `compareTo(Person p)` method from the `Comparable` interface.

If you have something like this in your `compareTo` function:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person p) {
    return sName.compareTo(p.sName);
}
```

Then the TreeSet will see both `Person("Mary", "O Keefe")` and `Person("Rosella", "O Keefe")` Person objects as the same object.

The reason for this is because a Set *only contains unique elements*. It uses the `compareTo` function to determine whether an element already exists in the set.

To fix this issue, you will need to compare with *both* the first name and surname like so:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person p) {
    return fName.compareTo(p.fName) + sName.compareTo(p.sName);
}
```